# Moving files with target selection

Tags: automator, finder

I would like to create a workflow / applescripts from automator to move files but after I drop the files to the droplet it should ask me where should I put it.

I want to select with my pre-defined target location.
Ex.
Target:
A> Path_A
B> Path_B
Etc.

I can see in Automator that "move finder items" can put multiple variables but somehow when I run it with "show this action" ticked it shows me only 1 variable.

Answer (score 0):

Little vague what you need exactly. There would be several options.

You can use the choose folder action in automator and save that path into a variable to use in your applescript.
You can also use

```
choose folder
```

in Applescript to prompt the user to choose a path.